# Inappropriate value for attribute "launch_configuration": string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

unable to attach Launch configuration to Auto scaling group, written in terraform

```
#creating Launch Configuration
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf" {
  name          = "lc"
  image_id      = "ami-0e306788ff2473ccb"
  instance_type = "${var.instance-type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.webserver-sg.id}"]
  key_name = "${var.key-name}"
  
  

}

variable "instance-type" {
    default = "t2.micro"
  
}
variable "key-name" {
    default = "terraform"
  }

# creating Auto Scaling Group
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my-asg" {
  name                      = "my-asg"
  max_size                  = 3
  min_size                  = 2
  desired_capacity          = 2
  #launch_configuration      = ["aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.id"]
  launch_configuration =  ["${aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.name}"] #attaching launch config to asg
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["subnet-2a444242" ,"subnet-9a8937e1", "subnet-b897e3f4"]

}
```

**whicle executing the code am getting error: Inappropriate value for attribute "launch_configuration": string required.**
[Console out put after executing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhwtI.png)

Comment: Remove the square brackets around the value. Square brackets are turning it into a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

launch_configuration does not take a list but a single string.
Please get rid of [ ] and try again.

Comment: "${aws_launch_configuration.mylc.name}"